# Can't Save Edits to PHP Configuration File

Tags: php, notepad++

I am trying to edit php.ini on my local testing server using Notepad++, but each time I try to save the changes, I get this error message...

[image: php.ini Notepad++ Save Error]

What do I have to do in order to edit the configuration file? Do I somehow have to shut off PHP and then turn it back on?

Comment: Run N++ as Administrator or change the file's permissions first.

Comment: @putvande PHP doesn't lock PHP.ini while it is running.  That isn't the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PHP.ini is likely in a location that requires administrator privileges to edit.

Close Notepad++.  Go find its shortcut and right click while holding control.  You should now have a "run as Administrator" option.  Click that, and then try to edit the file.

Comment: +1. Alternatively, in Win7 (not sure about Win8), you can right click the icon on the taskbar, right click the name of the program in the little popup that appears and click "Run as Administrator" to launch a new instance of the program with admin privileges.

Comment: @jedwards I have Windows 8.1, and that's how I did it. I am trying to accept Brad's answer, but StackOverflow tells me I have to wait 10 minutes. :-/

Comment: I get this error while running notepad++ as admin